# call a function from another scope

Tags: javascript

please help to run a function that is in a different scope

have the following code:

```
function a(){
    var rrr = 8;
    function aim(arg){
        console.log('aim' + arg);
        console.log(rrr);
    }
};

function b(){
    a.aim('this is argument');
};
```

call `a.aim ('this is argument');` does not work, the console displays a message

> Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined

tried to call through apply. also unsuccessfully

Comment: Well, yes, "different scope" by definition means you can't access it. You have to rearrange your code, but how exactly is hard to tell with such pseudo code and no real use case.

Comment: There's a zillion ways to do this. See [Eloquent JavaScript, Chapter 8](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter8.html) and [Introduction to Object Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) over at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/). The Revealing Module pattern is one of many, and they all can be useful depending on the scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using revealing module pattern:

```
var a = function(){
   var rrr = 8;
   function aim(arg){
    console.log('aim' + arg);
        console.log(rrr);
   }

   return {      
      aim: aim
   }
}();

function b() {
    a.aim('test');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function a(){
    var rrr = 8;
    return function aim(arg){
        console.log('aim' + arg);
        console.log(rrr);
    }
};


function b(){
    var aim = a();
    aim('this is argument');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to `a` function as an object you need to create it first. Also, `aim` should be a property of this function (class)

```
function a() {
    var rrr = 8;
    this.aim = function(arg) {
        console.log('aim' + arg);
        console.log(rrr);
    }
};

function b() {
    var aa = new a();
    aa.aim('this is argument');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the 2 minor changes:

```
function a(){
    var rrr = 8;
    this.aim = function(arg){
        console.log('aim' + arg);
        console.log(rrr);
    }
};

var aa = new a();
function b(){
    aa.aim('this is argument');
};
```